# CKEditor - move skins folder somewhere else

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor for the first time and trying to do something that I thought would be very simple to do but so far I've had no success.

Essentially I want to place the editor.js, config.js and styles.js in a scripts folder but want the "Skins" folder that contains the css and images to appear within a separate "Styles" folder.

The application consists of a simple view that displays the editor on load.

The code to display the editor is a follows:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss = '/Styles/CKEditor/';
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor');
});
```

The HTML within my view is as follows:

```
@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/ckeditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<textarea id="editor" name="editor"></textarea>
```

This is an MVC application and the scripts are rendered at the end of the body within the layout view.

The editor will not display in any browser. As I understand it setting the contentsCss property should do the trick.

If I place the skins beneath my script folder it works fine. I can see in the generated source that it is adding a link to the header pointing to /Scripts/Skins/moono..., but I want it to add a reference to /Styles/Skins/moono...

Is what I am trying to do feasable and if so what am I missing here? I was expecting this to be simple.

As a work around I could just add some routing rules that redirects the relevant request to a different location, but I'd rather get to the bottom of the issue before I do this.

Further information:

- My application is an ASP.net 4.5/MVC 4 app.
- I'm referencing angular because I'll be using that once I've sorted this issue. I have tried removing all references to angular but the problem still persists.
- I've tried setting the contentsCss property in the following ways:

  - Directly using CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss
  - Within the config.js file. The sample assigns an anonymous function to CKEDITOR.editorConfig and in there you can manipulate congif entries.
  - Passing a config parameter when calling the "replace" method on the CKEditor object.
  - I've tried manipulating the contentsCss property both before and after the call to replace.
- I'm using the latest version of CKEditor (4.2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Richard Deeming, I've found the answer.

I'm using the default moono style, so I needed to set the CKEDITOR.config.skin property as follows:

```
CKEDITOR.config.skin = 'moono,/Styles/CKEditor/Skins/moono/'
```

My final code now looks like this:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    CKEDITOR.config.skin = 'moono,/Styles/CKEditor/Skins/moono/';
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor');
});
```

You have to set the url to the actual folder containing the skin itself (I thought CKEditor might append skins/mooono itself but it doesn't).

I also found that you must include the final '/' from the URL.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [the documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-skin), you need to specify the path as part of the skin name:

```
CKEDITOR.skinName = 'CKeditor,/Styles/CKeditor/';
```

Comment: Hi Richard. Thank you for you response. I had tried that but your answer prompted me to try it again and lead me to the answer which I will post in a minute.